# Flask-SQLAlchemy check if database server is responsive

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using flask-SQLAlchemy for my webservice. I would like to have an endpoint that checks status of the utilized MySQL database availability/responsiveness. How would I go about it? Thanks.

Here are relevant pieces of my code:

mywebsvc.py

```
...
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://mylogin:mypw@localhost/mydb'

db.init_app(app)
...
```

models_shared.py

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

models.py

```
from models_shared import db

class Car(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    make = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    color = db.Column(db.String(64), index=False, unique=False)
```

routes.py

```
...
@app.route('/is_available', methods=['GET'])
def is_available():
    #???
```

Answer (score 16):

There is a fancy library for writing end-point checking condition of the service - [healthcheck](https://github.com/Runscope/healthcheck).

> It's useful for asserting that your dependencies are up and running
>   and your application can respond to HTTP requests. The Healthcheck
>   functions are exposed via a user defined flask route so you can use an
>   external monitoring application (Monit, Nagios, Runscope, etc.) to
>   check the status and uptime of your application.

You can use it instead of manually creating end-point because there are some features out of the box (for example [EnvironmentDump](https://github.com/Runscope/healthcheck#the-environmentdump-class)).

In my application, I had the same need so I implemented check if database is responsive

```
app = Flask(__name__)

# wrap the flask app and give a heathcheck url
health = HealthCheck(app, "/healthcheck")

def health_database_status():
    is_database_working = True
    output = 'database is ok'

    try:
        # to check database we will execute raw query
        session = DatabaseSession.get_database_session()
        session.execute('SELECT 1')
    except Exception as e:
        output = str(e)
        is_database_working = False

    return is_database_working, output

health.add_check(health_database_status)
```

As I see, in your application you can execute query with `db.engine.execute('SELECT 1')`.

Comment: i think it's `db.session.execute('SELECT 1')`

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding a [connection timeout](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html) to your SQLAlchemy engine connection:

> MySQL features an automatic connection close behavior, for connections that have been idle for eight hours or more. To circumvent having this issue, use the pool_recycle option which controls the maximum age of any connection…

Then you can check if the connection timed out to see if the database falls below your threshold of availability.