# Handling database disconnect

Tags: python, database, postgresql, flask, error-handling

I would like to have some advise on how to handle an error in case of my database server is disconnected.

Let's say I have 2 server running:

1. API
2. Database

Using postman to test my endpoint, I create a user with success then I turn off my database server and try to create another user. At the point the request is loading without responses.

I am using Python and Flask

Any advise ?

Thanks

Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30307658/flask-sqlalchemy-check-if-database-server-is-responsive). It's based on using SQLAlchemy engine for connecting and transacting on the database but can be a good start.